# Can't get the Canvas to be positioned at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement the [Google balls HTML5 canvas logo](http://rawkes.com/lab/google-balls-logo) in my website (eventually I will change the word 'Google' to my name). However, I already have a menu, and I can't get the logo to appear above the menu.

When I comment the last block of my CSS3 (shown below), the logo gets to appear at the top, but the menu disappears.

Here's what I'm getting right now (without commenting the last block in my CSS3):
[image]

Note that there's 60px **menu margin** above both the Google balls and the menu. Ideally, I would like to increase the **menu margin** to maybe 150px, then add the "myName" balls centered above the menu.

Here's the HTML5 code:

GoogleBalls.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <title>myHomepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id= "c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS3 code:

style.css:

```
/* This is for the menu */

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

/* This is for Google balls */

/* If I comment the following, I will see Google balls at 
 * the top of the page (which is what I want), but the menu disappears!*/

#c {
    position: absolute;
}
```

My javascript code:

main.js:

```
$(function() {
    var canvas = $("#c");
    var canvasHeight;
    var canvasWidth;
    var ctx;
    var dt = 0.1;

    var pointCollection;

    function init() {
        updateCanvasDimensions();

        var g = [new Point(202, 78, 0.0, 9, "#ed9d33"), new Point(348, 83, 0.0, 9, "#d44d61"), 
        new Point(256, 69, 0.0, 9, "#4f7af2"), new Point(214, 59, 0.0, 9, "#ef9a1e"), new Point(265, 36, 0.0, 9, "#4976f3"), 
        new Point(300, 78, 0.0, 9, "#269230"), new Point(294, 59, 0.0, 9, "#1f9e2c"), new Point(45, 88, 0.0, 9, "#1c48dd"), 
        new Point(268, 52, 0.0, 9, "#2a56ea"), new Point(73, 83, 0.0, 9, "#3355d8"), new Point(294, 6, 0.0, 9, "#36b641"), 
        new Point(235, 62, 0.0, 9, "#2e5def"), new Point(353, 42, 0.0, 8, "#d53747"), new Point(336, 52, 0.0, 8, "#eb676f"), 
        new Point(208, 41, 0.0, 8, "#f9b125"), new Point(321, 70, 0.0, 8, "#de3646"), new Point(8, 60, 0.0, 8, "#2a59f0"), 
        new Point(180, 81, 0.0, 8, "#eb9c31"), new Point(146, 65, 0.0, 8, "#c41731"), new Point(145, 49, 0.0, 8, "#d82038"), 
        new Point(246, 34, 0.0, 8, "#5f8af8"), new Point(169, 69, 0.0, 8, "#efa11e"), new Point(273, 99, 0.0, 8, "#2e55e2"), 
        new Point(248, 120, 0.0, 8, "#4167e4"), new Point(294, 41, 0.0, 8, "#0b991a"), new Point(267, 114, 0.0, 8, "#4869e3"), 
        new Point(78, 67, 0.0, 8, "#3059e3"), new Point(294, 23, 0.0, 8, "#10a11d"), new Point(117, 83, 0.0, 8, "#cf4055"), 
        new Point(137, 80, 0.0, 8, "#cd4359"), new Point(14, 71, 0.0, 8, "#2855ea"), 
        new Point(331, 80, 0.0, 8, "#ca273c"), new Point(25, 82, 0.0, 8, "#2650e1"), new Point(233, 46, 0.0, 8, "#4a7bf9"), 
        new Point(73, 13, 0.0, 8, "#3d65e7"), new Point(327, 35, 0.0, 6, "#f47875"), new Point(319, 46, 0.0, 6, "#f36764"), 
        new Point(256, 81, 0.0, 6, "#1d4eeb"), new Point(244, 88, 0.0, 6, "#698bf1"), new Point(194, 32, 0.0, 6, "#fac652"), 
        new Point(97, 56, 0.0, 6, "#ee5257"), new Point(105, 75, 0.0, 6, "#cf2a3f"), new Point(42, 4, 0.0, 6, "#5681f5"), 
        new Point(10, 27, 0.0, 6, "#4577f6"), new Point(166, 55, 0.0, 6, "#f7b326"), new Point(266, 88, 0.0, 6, "#2b58e8"), 
        new Point(178, 34, 0.0, 6, "#facb5e"), new Point(100, 65, 0.0, 6, "#e02e3d"), new Point(343, 32, 0.0, 6, "#f16d6f"), 
        new Point(59, 5, 0.0, 6, "#507bf2"), new Point(27, 9, 0.0, 6, "#5683f7"), new Point(233, 116, 0.0, 6, "#3158e2"), 
        new Point(123, 32, 0.0, 6, "#f0696c"), new Point(6, 38, 0.0, 6, "#3769f6"), new Point(63, 62, 0.0, 6, "#6084ef"), 
        new Point(6, 49, 0.0, 6, "#2a5cf4"), new Point(108, 36, 0.0, 6, "#f4716e"), new Point(169, 43, 0.0, 6, "#f8c247"), 
        new Point(137, 37, 0.0, 6, "#e74653"), new Point(318, 58, 0.0, 6, "#ec4147"), new Point(226, 100, 0.0, 5, "#4876f1"), 
        new Point(101, 46, 0.0, 5, "#ef5c5c"), new Point(226, 108, 0.0, 5, "#2552ea"), new Point(17, 17, 0.0, 5, "#4779f7"), 
        new Point(232, 93, 0.0, 5, "#4b78f1")];

        gLength = g.length;

        // I commented this so that Google balls appear at the top of the page
        //
        //for (var i = 0; i < gLength; i++) {
        //  g[i].curPos.x = (canvasWidth/2 - 180) + g[i].curPos.x;
        //  g[i].curPos.y = (canvasHeight/2 - 65) + g[i].curPos.y;

        //  g[i].originalPos.x = (canvasWidth/2 - 180) + g[i].originalPos.x;
        //  g[i].originalPos.y = (canvasHeight/2 - 65) + g[i].originalPos.y;
        //};

        pointCollection = new PointCollection();
        pointCollection.points = g;

        initEventListeners();
        timeout();
    };

    function initEventListeners() {
        $(window).bind('resize', updateCanvasDimensions).bind('mousemove', onMove);

        canvas.get(0).ontouchmove = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            onTouchMove(e);
        };

        canvas.get(0).ontouchstart = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        };
    };

    function updateCanvasDimensions() {
        canvas.attr({height: $(window).height(), width: $(window).width()});
        canvasWidth = canvas.width();
        canvasHeight = canvas.height();
        draw();
    };

    function onMove(e) {
        if (pointCollection)
            pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    };

    function onTouchMove(e) {
        if (pointCollection)
        pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.targetTouches[0].pageX, e.targetTouches[0].pageY);
    };

    function timeout() {
        draw();
        update();
        setTimeout(function() { timeout() }, 30);
    };

    function draw() {
        var tmpCanvas = canvas.get(0);
        if (tmpCanvas.getContext == null) {
            return; 
        };

        ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        if (pointCollection)
            pointCollection.draw();
    };

    function update() {     
    if (pointCollection)
        pointCollection.update();
};

    function Vector(x, y, z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        this.addX = function(x) {
            this.x += x;
        };

        this.addY = function(y) {
            this.y += y;
        };

         this.addZ = function(z) {
             this.z += z;
        };

         this.set = function(x, y, z) {
             this.x = x; 
             this.y = y;
             this.z = z;
         };
    };

    function PointCollection() {
        this.mousePos = new Vector(0, 0);
        this.points = new Array();

        this.newPoint = function(x, y, z) {
            var point = new Point(x, y, z);
            this.points.push(point);
            return point;
        };

        this.update = function() {      
            var pointsLength = this.points.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < pointsLength; i++) {
                var point = this.points[i];
                if (point == null)
                    continue;
                var dx = this.mousePos.x - point.curPos.x;
                var dy = this.mousePos.y - point.curPos.y;
                var dd = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
                var d = Math.sqrt(dd);

                if (d < 150) {
                    point.targetPos.x = (this.mousePos.x < point.curPos.x) ? point.curPos.x - dx : point.curPos.x - dx;
                    point.targetPos.y = (this.mousePos.y < point.curPos.y) ? point.curPos.y - dy : point.curPos.y - dy;
                } else {
                    point.targetPos.x = point.originalPos.x;
                    point.targetPos.y = point.originalPos.y;
                };
                point.update();
            };
        };

        this.draw = function() {
            var pointsLength = this.points.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < pointsLength; i++) {
                var point = this.points[i];

                if (point == null)
                    continue;
                point.draw();
            };
        };
    };

    function Point(x, y, z, size, colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
        this.curPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
        this.friction = 0.8;
        this.originalPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
        this.radius = size;
        this.size = size;
        this.springStrength = 0.1;
        this.targetPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
        this.velocity = new Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        this.update = function() {
            var dx = this.targetPos.x - this.curPos.x;
            var ax = dx * this.springStrength;
            this.velocity.x += ax;
            this.velocity.x *= this.friction;
            this.curPos.x += this.velocity.x;

            var dy = this.targetPos.y - this.curPos.y;
            var ay = dy * this.springStrength;
            this.velocity.y += ay;
            this.velocity.y *= this.friction;
            this.curPos.y += this.velocity.y;

            var dox = this.originalPos.x - this.curPos.x;
            var doy = this.originalPos.y - this.curPos.y;
            var dd = (dox * dox) + (doy * doy);
            var d = Math.sqrt(dd);

            this.targetPos.z = d/100 + 1;
            var dz = this.targetPos.z - this.curPos.z;
            var az = dz * this.springStrength;
            this.velocity.z += az;
            this.velocity.z *= this.friction;
            this.curPos.z += this.velocity.z;

            this.radius = this.size*this.curPos.z;
            if (this.radius < 1) this.radius = 1;
        };

        this.draw = function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.curPos.x, this.curPos.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            ctx.fill();
        };
    };

    init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky without seeing some working code (like on jsfiddle) but I'm guessing you need to float both the menu and logo (canvas) elements, making sure to call clear:left on the menu element to force it to the next level.

Edit: you wanted the logo centered; use can use `margin: 0 auto;`